# Pandas Apply Syntax

Tags: python, pandas

I can't figure out how to apply a simple function to every row of a column in a Panda data frame.

Example:

```
def delLastThree(x):
    x = x.strip()
    x = x[:-3]
    return x

arr = ['test123','test234','test453']
arrDF = pandas.DataFrame(arr)
arrDF.columns = ['colOne']
arrDF['colOne'].apply(delLastThree)
print arrDF
```

I would expect the code below to return 'test' for every row. Instead it prints the original values.

How do I apply the delLastThree function to every row in the DF?

Comment: For future examples, to get this specific example to work the error is in the second to last line. It should be: arrDF['colOne'] = arrDF['colOne'].apply(delLastThree). Chosen answer's suggestion is better to use though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a `pd.Series` when selecting using single brackets with `df['colOne']`.

Either use `.apply(func, axis=1)` on a `DataFrame`, ie either when selecting with `[['colOne']]`, or without selecting any columns. However, if you use `.apply(axis=1)`, the result is a `pd.Series`, so you need to modify the function to `.str` for `.string` methods.

With the `pd.Series` resulting from selecting with `['colOne']`, you can use either just `.apply()` or `.map()`.

```
def delLastThree_series(x):
    x = x.strip()
    x = x[:-3]
    return x

def delLastThree_df(x):
    x = x.str.strip()
    x = x.str[:-3]
    return x

arr = ['test123','test234','test453']
arrDF = pd.DataFrame(arr)

arrDF.columns = ['colOne']
```

Now use either

```
arrDF.apply(delLastThree_df, axis=1)
arrDF[['colOne']].apply(delLastThree_df, axis=1)
```

or

```
arrDF['colOne'].apply(delLastThree_series)
arrDF['colOne'].map(delLastThree_series, axis=1)
```

to get:

```
  colOne
0   test
1   test
2   test
```

You could of course also just:

```
arrDF['colOne'].str.strip().str[:-3]
```

Comment: You know, I tried that and got a "TypeError: delLastThree() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"

Answer (score 1):

use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function for series (single column):

```
In [15]: arrDF['colOne'].map(delLastThree)
Out[15]:
0    test
1    test
2    test
Name: colOne, dtype: object
```

or if you want to change it:

```
In [16]: arrDF['colOne'] = arrDF['colOne'].map(delLastThree)

In [17]: arrDF
Out[17]:
  colOne
0   test
1   test
2   test
```

but as @Stefan said this will be much faster and more efficient and more "Pandonic":

```
arrDF['colOne'] = arrDF['colOne'].str.strip().str[:-3]
```

or if you want to strip all trailing spaces and numbers:

```
arrDF['colOne'] = arrDF['colOne'].str.replace(r'[\s\d]+$', '')
```

test:

```
In [21]: arrDF['colOne'].str.replace(r'[\s\d]+$', '')
Out[21]:
0    test
1    test
2    test
Name: colOne, dtype: object
```